# Export PrestaShop data (customers, addresses, orders) when changed

Tags: export, prestashop

In our company we want to use PrestaShop as online shop system. But we also have an ERP-System which needs customers, addresses and orders, too.

Therefore i have to synchronize the data. First i thought that i just request all data via webservice calls. But this would mean i have to implement polling which is a 'dirty' solution in my opinion.

Is there any module or another possible solution that exports the data everytime when new data is inserted or existing data is changed / deleted?

I'm very new to PrestaShop. Maybe somebody could help me :)

Thanks in advance

Best wishes

Andi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time that an object is added, modified or deleted a function is called:

Function `add` from `Object` class:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.get_class($this).'AddAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

Function `update` from `Object` class:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.get_class($this).'UpdateAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

Function `delete` from `Object` class:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.get_class($this).'DeleteAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

Then you can create a module and use these hooks to integrate it with your ERP.